# Use different allocators for std::unordered_map hashes and values

Tags: c++, stl

In a program I am working on, a huge percentage of time is spent in the default allocator allocating memory for a `std::unordered_map`. The map has data added and removed frequently, and the allocations that happen on every insert are limiting the program's performance. (Performance is particularly bad because all 64 cores on the machine are allocating/deallocating nodes of the same type, and there seems to be contention for some internal lock.)

In order to improve performance and lower allocator pressure, I'm trying to use a pool allocator (`boost::object_pool`) in order to reuse memory. In addition, I expect there may be some performance gain in the program from data locality improvements if the keys/values are stored in a local pool.

`std::unordered_map` seems to allocate memory for hashes, and separately for the key-value pairs objects (as `std::pair<const Key, Value>`). However, there's only one allocator template parameter, and this seems to set the allocator used for both objects. How can I use different allocators for these two things?

In some circumstances, I see `std::scoped_allocator_adaptor` suggested, but as best I can tell this is actually for specifying different allocators in nested containers, rather than within the same container.

Comment: Can you perhaps elaborate on *why* you want this? What is the *actual* problem you have, that you want to solve this way? Perhaps there are better solutions to that problem?

Comment: Can't you use partial template specialisation on your allocator to special-case `std::pair<k, v>` allocations?

Comment: Try jemalloc for your whole application, it will probably solve all of your heap bottlenecks, especially with that many cores.